# Thrift or Protocol buffer as cross-language serialization solution?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, thrift

I've already chosen to use thrift as RPC framework in a project. This project has a lot of serialization / deserialization operations (e.g., store the data to disks). And the serialized format should be accessible for at least C++/Java/Python. It seems that thrift's serialization solution is more complicated than Protobuf (e.g., it needs to create a protocol before serializing an object).

So my question is: is it worth to use Protobuf for the serialization / deserialization part even if thrift is *capable* of this task?

Comment: I can not answer the question, but I think Protobuf has more tools available to it (http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns) which may be useful if you are searilising to disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree that Thrift is a better choice for cross language RPC than Protobuf RPC ( see http://pjklauser.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/why-googles-protobuf-rpc-will-not-reach-widespread-adoption/ ). If you're using thrift already it's difficult to justify using a different "library" for serialization to file/storage. You'll need to write endless mapping code. Both libraries will have different maintenance cycles which you need to maintain independently which will give extra future effort. The cost of writing a line or two more code, or save one or two bytes of space, or save a microsecond of CPU time will be nothing compared to your additional efforts.

Comment: My main concern is the overhead of development. The efficiency of two  solutions are both OK for me.